# insert into mysql using php/html - not work

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm trying to enter data into a mysql database using php / html form but it isn't working and I don't know why. The record is not inserted and the page just refresh

**I apologize for some of it being written in Danish**

I have 2 files 1 with html and php and 1 with only php

My database: [Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKSXh.png)

This is the html form and php:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

                    // echo "<pre>", print_r($_POST), "</pre>";

                    $apply_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST ['apply_name']);
                    $apply_age = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST ['apply_age']);
                    $apply_ingame_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST ['apply_ingame_name']);
                    $apply_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST ['apply_email']);
                    $apply_steamID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST ['apply_steamID']);
                    $apply_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST ['apply_text']);

                    $errors = []; // Array

                    if ($apply_name == "") {
                        $errors['apply_name'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                  <strong>Du har ikke angivet noget navn!</strong>
                                </div>";
                    } elseif (strlen($apply_name) < 2) {
                        $errors['apply_name'] = "<div class='alert alert-info'>
                                  <strong>Dit navn skal minimum være 2 karatere</strong>
                                </div>";
                    }

                    if ($apply_age == "") {
                        $errors['create_apply_age'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                  <strong>Du har ikke angivet din alder!</strong>
                                </div>";
                    }

                    if ($apply_ingame_name == "") {
                        $errors['create_apply_ingame_name'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                  <strong>Du har ikke angivet noget In-Game navn!</strong>
                                </div>";
                    } elseif (strlen($apply_ingame_name) < 2) {
                        $errors['create_apply_ingame_name'] = "<div class='alert alert-info'>
                                  <strong>Dit In-Game navn skal minimum være 2 karatere</strong>
                                </div>";
                    }

                    if ($apply_email == "") {
                        $errors['create_apply_email'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                  <strong>Email skal udfyldes!</strong>
                                </div>";
                    } elseif (!filter_var($apply_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                        $errors['create_apply_email'] = "<div class='alert alert-info'>
                                  <strong>Email er ugyldig</strong>
                                </div>";
                    }

                    if ($apply_steamID == "") {
                        $errors['create_apply_steamID'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                  <strong>Du har ikke angivet noget SteamID!</strong>
                                </div>";
                    } elseif (strlen($apply_steamID) < 18) {
                        $errors['create_apply_steamID'] = "<div class='alert alert-info'>
                                  <strong>Dit SteamID ser sådan her ud STEAM_0:0:XXXXXXXX</strong>
                                </div>";
                    }

                    if ($apply_text == "") {
                        $errors['create_apply_text'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                                  <strong>Du har ikke skrevet noget om dig selv!</strong>
                                </div>";
                    }

                    if (empty($errors)) {
                        // Send ansøning

                        $created = create_apply($apply_name, $apply_age, $apply_ingame_name, $apply_email, $apply_steamID, $apply_text);

                        if ($created) {
                            echo "
                                <div class='alert alert-info'>
                                  <strong>Din ansøning er sendt.</strong>
                                </div>
                            ";
                        } else {
                            // Ansøning kunne ikke sendes
                            $create_error = "Ansøningen kunne ikke sendes, SteamID eksistere i forvejen";
                        }

                    } else {
                        $create_error = "Der opstod en fejl, Prøv igen";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            
            <section>
                <hr>
                <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="signup" method="post" name="signup" action="?p=askforsignup">
                                <?php 
                                    if (isset($errors['apply_name'])) {
                                        echo $errors['apply_name'];
                                    }
                                ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Navn <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><input class="form-control" id="mem_name" name="apply_name" placeholder="Navn" type="text" value="" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                <?php 
                                    if (isset($errors['create_apply_age'])) {
                                        echo $errors['create_apply_age'];
                                    }
                                ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Alder <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input class="form-control" id="age" name="apply_age" placeholder="Alder" type="date" value="" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                <?php 
                                    if (isset($errors['create_apply_ingame_name'])) {
                                        echo $errors['create_apply_ingame_name'];
                                    }
                                ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">In-Game Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span><input class="form-control" id="ingame_game" name="apply_ingame_name" placeholder="In-Game Name" type="text" value="" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                <?php 
                                    if (isset($errors['create_apply_email'])) {
                                        echo $errors['create_apply_email'];
                                    }
                                ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span><input class="form-control" id="emailid" name="apply_email" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="" >
                            </div><small>Your Email is being used for ensuring the security of your account, authorization and access recovery.</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                <?php 
                                    if (isset($errors['create_apply_steamID'])) {
                                        echo $errors['create_apply_steamID'];
                                    }
                                ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Steam ID <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-8">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-steam"></i></span><input class="form-control" id="contactnum" name="apply_steamID" placeholder="Steam ID" type="text" value="" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                <?php 
                                    if (isset($errors['create_apply_text'])) {
                                        echo $errors['create_apply_text'];
                                    }
                                ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Beskriv dig selv <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-id-card"></i></span>
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="message" name="apply_text" placeholder="Beskriv dig selv." ></textarea>
                            </div><br>
                            <div class="col-xs-offset-8 col-xs-10 pull-right">
                                <input class="btn btn-primary" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div><!--/.col-sm-8-->
    </div>
```

And this is the php code:

```
function create_apply($apply_name, $apply_age, $apply_ingame_name, $apply_email, $apply_steamID, $apply_text) {

    global $db;

    $steamID_exists = steamID_exists($apply_steamID);

    if ($steamID_exists == false) {

        $apply_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $apply_name);
        $apply_age = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $apply_age);
        $apply_ingame_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $apply_ingame_name);
        $apply_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $apply_email);
        $apply_steamID = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $apply_steamID);
        $apply_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $apply_text);

        $query = "INSERT INTO member_applys
                  (apply_name, apply_age, apply_ingame_name, apply_email, apply_steamID, apply_text, apply_date)
                  VALUES
                  ('$apply_name', '$apply_age', '$apply_ingame_name', '$apply_email', '$apply_steamID', '$apply_text', NOW())";

        $result = $db->query($query);

        return true;
    } else {
        // Brugeren eksistere opret = falsk
        return false;
    }
    }
```

---

#### Solved

the problem was google autocomplete was on not off

Comment: I don't see you calling the `create_apply()` method.

Comment: and what does this method do? `steamID_exists()`.

Comment: plus, it's unknown if you did connect (successfully). So, *what say ye?* Magic just doesn't happen you know, it's created.

Comment: I love it when they post and leave/ignore. [This is a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard#comment526922_358600) in a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358600/1415724) that was created for posts just like this.

Comment: I do call the create_apply() after  if (empty($errors)) and the method steamID_exists()  check if the steamID exists in the database

Comment: must've been lunchtime over your way earlier, huh?

Comment: something like that yea

Answer (score 0):

Di you be sure that your script call well the form?
I see:

```
 ....action="?p=askforsignup">
```

try:

```
 ....action="your_script.php">
```

Comment: That's because I'm using php switch